# Can I create a usercontrol that is available only inside a template?

Tags: c#, templates, user-controls

Anyone have an idea how I can create a usercontrol that is only available inside the template of another user control? The best example I can think of is the PostBackTrigger and AsyncPostbackTrigger. These "controls" are only available inside the Triggers "template" of the UpdatePanel. Basically, I want to be able to include placeholder elements inside of the template that are then rendered into a seperate usercontrol using only the attributes assigned in the aspx portion of the page.

an example to try and make things more clear:

```
<usercontrol1>
    <mytemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><usercontrol2 ID="uc2" runat="server" Text="Text" Width="200" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </mytemplate>
</usercontrol1>
```

In this example, usercontrol2 would not show up in Intellisense unless I was typing inside usercontrol1's template.

Comment: Completely pointless answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Sadly this cannot be done with User Controls.</strike> In order to do this you will have to build a [templated server control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx).

Or using [Templated User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx) per [Kbrimington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404854/kbrimington)

Comment: Note also that a user control can be templated. (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx).

Comment: @kbrimington Thanks for the update... I have included it in the answer for future reference.